# Developer Policy 6.1: Verify that you have integrated Login correctly. Your app shouldn't crash or hang during the testing process

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, policies

we received an email from Facebook review team telling us that our live app (website) is being reviewed and later got another templated email saying that our login is crashing or hanging, suggested we fix it, and gave us a bunch of links to the best practices on how to fix the FB login integration.

The problem is we don't use FB in our login (we just use their Marketing API) and, to us, the login works just fine.

Anyone else with a similar experience out there? If so, what did you do?